# Have problem to navigate to a docker-compose.yml file

Tags: python, cmd, docker-compose

[image]

I need to navigate to my docker-compose.yml file but writing cd docker-compose.yml doesn't work. The Terminal tells me that the catalog name is wrong or invalid, couldn't find the right translation. I want to navigate to the docker-compose so i can run docker up in the Terminal.

Comment: you are trying to ``cd`` - change directory - to a file, not a folder. If you are trying to edit the ``docker-compose.yaml`` file then open it via the ``File`` menu.

Comment: docker-compose.yml is not a directory its a file in the root dir of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You are already in the directory for docker-compose, but you can't cd to a file, you want to run commands for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `cd app`.

`docker-compose.yml` is a file, inside the directory `app`. Since `cd` moves you to a directory, it makes no sense to launch it on a file.

The command you want once you are in the same folder as your docker-compose.yml is `docker-compose up`.

So to sum it up:

```
cd app
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to **cd** into a file, you can use docker-compose command to run the file.